# multibranch pipeline job do not start the build step even downstream finished building

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I run a multibranch pipeline with jenkinsfile and I got 'Scheduling project: caiwu » sis-server-test',but not 'Starting building: ' appears until the job sis-test funish building,who can give me a hand?

```
pipeline{
    agent {label 'test-slave'}      
    stages{
        stage('deploy'){
            steps{
                echo 'deploy...'
                build job:'/folder/sis-test', propagate: true, wait: true                
            }            
        }

    }
}

here are the build log
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] build (Building caiwu » sis-server-test)
Scheduling project: caiwu » sis-server-test
Aborted by ***
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite difficult to understand. If the problem is that you do NOT want it to wait for the job, your current line:

`build job:'/folder/sis-test', propagate: true, wait: true`

Will need to be changed to

`build job:'/folder/sis-test', propagate: true, wait: false`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my problem is that it should start 'Starting building: ' step after the  downstream job finished building but it not,any ideas?